# Behavior of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\{n \xi \} - \frac{1}{2})$ for irrational number $\xi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, equidistribution

Consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ( \{  n \xi \} - \frac{1}{2})
$$
where $\{ \}$ denotes the fractional part and $\xi$ is some irrational number. It clearly does not converge but can we show that it does not tend to $\infty$ or $-\infty$? Would it also be true that it bounded?

The problem seems to be related to equidistributed sequences. Since ${(\{ n \xi  \} )}_{n \geq 1}$ is equidistributed we have that

$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(\{n\xi\}- \frac{1}{2}) \to 0
$$
as $N \to \infty$.
However, just the equidistribution property cannot be enough. Consider for example a sequence $(a_n)$ given by $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd or a power of $2$ and $a_n= -1$ otherwise. Then $(a_n)$ is equidistributed on $ \{ -1,1 \}$ but

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \infty.
$$

Comment: [Slightly reminiscent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358555/17064), cross-linked for completeness

Answer (score 14):

This is studied in detail in [Sums of Fractional Parts of Integer Multiples of an Irrational](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X85710128)
The
sum
$$C(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \bigl( \{  n \xi \} - \tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)$$
satisfies $|C(N)|>c\log N$ for infinitely many $N$. The coefficient $c\geq 1/720$.

Comment: Thank you! That is a great reference. This shows that the series cannot be bounded. However, I can't immediately see in the reference whether or not it is possible for $C(N) \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: The reference shows that $C(N) > c \log N$ and $C(N) < -c\log N$ both occur infinitely often; since $C(N)$ is Lipschitz in $N$, this already implies that $|C(N)|$ cannot diverge to infinity (there are infinitely many sign changes)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the reference only shows that $C(N) < - c \log N$ for infinitely many $N$ under certain conditions. In fact, Fact 5 in the reference gives an example of an irrational number where $C(N)$ is bounded below. Also, what do you mean by $C(N)$ being Lipschitz in $N$ and how is a Lipschitz condition relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see unboundedness of the sum is to notice that for 2-periodic $f(t) = \{t/2\}-1/2$ we have $|\hat{f}(m)| \gtrsim \frac{1}{|m|}$ for $m\neq 0$. Since the series
$$\sum_{m \neq 0} \left| \frac{\hat{f}(m)}{e^{i\pi  m x}-1}\right|^{2} \gtrsim \sum_{m \neq 0, \mathrm{dist}(mx, 2\mathbb{Z})<C/m} 1 = \infty 
$$
whenever $x$ is irrational, the claim follows from this [proposition](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358617/50901)